# Sending email with Joomla and Google Apps

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have the next settings in the Joomla Global Configuration panel.

```
**Mail Settings**  
Mailer: SMTP Server
Mail from: email@mydomain.com   
From Name: John Smith   
Sendmail Path:  
SMTP Authentication: Yes
SMTP Security: SSL  
SMTP Port: 465  
SMTP Username: email@mydomain.com       
SMTP Password: ******   
SMTP Host: gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

I am running Joomla 1.5.14.

I have in my google apps domain both IMAP and POP enabled.

When I try to send an email with an article link by clicking the small envelope icon I get the next feedback. "The e-mail cold not be send correctly". The SMTP validation seems to work because I do not get any SMTP error but the email is not sent. Any idea would be really appreciated!

I have tested with SMTP Host as *smtp.gmail.com* without success.

I have tried with sendmail defined as */usr/sbin/postfix* but without success.

## Solution

Set sendmail path to the sendmail command or point sendmail to postfix if you have postfix installed.

Set SMTP Host to smtp.gmail.com. I would look like:

```
**Mail Settings**  
Mailer: SMTP Server
Mail from: email@mydomain.com   
From Name: John Smith   
Sendmail Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP Authentication: Yes
SMTP Security: SSL  
SMTP Port: 465  
SMTP Username: email@mydomain.com       
SMTP Password: ******   
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: Proposed solution worked for me: Joomla 1.5.22 @ HostGator

Answer (score 2):

Mail Settings

```
Mailer: SMTP Server Mail from: emailmydomain.com
From Name: John Smith
Sendmail Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail 
SMTP Authentication: Yes 
SMTP Security: None
SMTP Port: 25
SMTP Username: emailmydomain.com
SMTP Password: **
SMTP Host: ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Comment: This was the only one working for me (Joomla 1.5.15, Sep 2012).

Answer (score 0):

I have Virtuemart 1.1.4 with Joomla! 1.5.15.

The configuration that works for me was (both for virtuemart and joomla contacts):

**Mail Settings**

```
Mailer: SMTP Server
Mail from: email@mydomain.com
From Name: John Smith
Sendmail Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP Authentication: Yes
SMTP Security: None
SMTP Port: 25
SMTP Username: email@mydomain.com
SMTP Password: ******
SMTP Host: ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
```